# How do I change the colors of the Ambiance & Radiance themes?

Tags: gnome, unity-2d, colors

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and i wanted to change colors in Ambiance/Radiance themes, by default it has orange and i wanted to change it to Blue,

I tried using gnome-color-chooser, but it didn't work?

any other ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you have do is copy radiance as backup and change setting.ini file in themes
by using.

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3/settings.ini
```

Edit:

```
nselected_bg_color:#f07746
```

So it says:

```
nselected_bg_color:#7FADFD
```

And do the same with gtk-2, using:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-2/gtkrc
```

Otherwise gtk-2 applications like chrome etc will have old orange color
and you are done. Reload the theme using gnome-tweak-tool.

Every GNOME-3 theme works with unity-3d perfectly but with 2D it has fallback window control problem when maximized (means in global panel it has fallback window controls which are ugly as hell, even the themes have unity folder in them and they work fine with 3D)

The colour used above [#7FADFD] is just one example of any number of hex colours that can be employed. Refer to [here](http://www.color-hex.com) for other hex colour codes.

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking to locally change the orange. (selected_bg_color) then in 11.10 & 12.04 you can simply set in gsettings or dconf-editor

Example  - setting to D3B37D

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-color-scheme "selected_bg_color:#D3B37D"
```

You can string other overrides in this fashion, example adding a `selected_fg_color` of 3c3b37

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-color-scheme "selected_bg_color:#D3B37D;selected_fg_color:#3c3b37"
```

screen shows where to add visually in dconf-editor, reflects the above command

[image]

Comment: graphical utility on screenshot is dconf-editor, not gconf-editor, although very similar, distribution of configurations isn't the same, and mistake made me install gconf-editor for no use at all :(

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of Light themes recolorations available on [GNOME-Look](http://gnome-look.org/).

Here's a partial list of some GTK+3 ones I found:

- [Humanity Icons Colors Version](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Humanity+Icons+Colors+Version?content=148933) *(You'll probably want to recolor your icons to match the rest of your theme)*
- [Ambiance & Radiance Colors Version](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance+%26+Radiance+Colors+Version?content=147891)
- [Ambiance DS Blue](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance+DS+Blue?content=146933) *(Tweaks the theme a bit more to change gradients and window buttons, but it also has a dark sidebar if that interests you)*

If you use 11.04 or older, you'll want to look for GTK+2 themes instead, but there are even *more* of those if you search for them.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change your whole theme, and rather modify the ecxisting ones you can use a nice gui tool called gtk-theme-config.

In order to install it, open a terminal and give the following commands one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shimmerproject/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk-theme-config
```