# How to get rid of the orange highlight in Unity?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change color of unity workspace border, and window resize](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107013/how-to-change-color-of-unity-workspace-border-and-window-resize)

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I'm using Unity. I also installed Adwaita theme and Elementary icons. Everything is cool. Highlightings are blue, as I want them to be, but there are some places where the default orange color remains:

1. When clicking on Workspace Switcher, the borders of the current or the selected workspace are still orange.
2. When dragging a window to the edges of the screen, the highlight effect for the Snap Window feature is still orange as well.

All other highlights are blue, according to the Adwaita theme.

So, how can I get rid of those two mentioned orange highlights and turn them into blue, following the Adwaita color theme?

Thanks for your attention.

brunces