# How to change the level of animation in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, 12.10, animations

In Ubuntu 10.04 there was a special option, which provided you an ability to change an animation level in one click. But it doesn't exist in Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10.

Which parameters I should change in **`Compiz Manager`** to set the 'Extra' level?

You can see the image of 10.04:

[image: here]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Extra Level does not exist anymore....

Instead, now you can customize animations more by using **Compiz Config Settings Manager**!

[image]

Execute this command to install it:

> sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

## Or....

Watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NihYajOfCu0&feature=related).

**NOTE**:

- [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-would-i-want-to-avoid-it)

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, that doesn't exist any more and we have to configure compiz manually from what I know. May be they removed it because of problems that may arise with configuring unity that way, I am not sure why.

Since you are on 12.04 or later, and I am assuming that you have compiz installed, if not use

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

to install it.

**NOTE:**

- [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-would-i-want-to-avoid-it)

From there on you can configure it in different ways as you like. Here are more places where you can read some material/guides on cool tweaks you can do with this tool once you install it.

http://www.howtogeek.com/101006/how-to-tweak-unity-on-ubuntu-with-the-compizconfig-settings-manager/

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/change-settings-ubuntu-unity-compizconfig-settings-manager/

[How to change color of unity workspace border, and window resize](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107013/how-to-change-color-of-unity-workspace-border-and-window-resize/158890#158890)

If you find some feature name not understandable, take a look at [compiz wiki](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM) and read what that feature does, and then tweak it if you want to. Happy tweaking!