# Looking for window resize color in ubuntu.css

Tags: 18.04, resize, css

I changed themes, but a few of the parts remained on ubuntu orange.

Found a post directing me to ubuntu.css and was able to change most of my color concerns there, except the color that started it all, the window resize color (see image). I was even able to change the border, but can't seem to find the window color itself.

[How to change color of unity workspace border, and window resize](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107013/how-to-change-color-of-unity-workspace-border-and-window-resize)

In the above post, further down after all the compiz settings, someone mentions the gtk.css file. However, when I open that, it's not settings that are modifiable, like the ubuntu.css file. It's just an url.

Anyone have an idea which file contains the color value for the window resize value? Or the heading I should be searching for in ubuntu.css? (PS, don't want to use compiz).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should search for this content in the css file.

```
/* Tiled window previews */
.tile-preview {
  background-color: rgba(27, 106, 203, 1);
  border: 1px solid #1b6acb; }

.tile-preview-left.on-primary {
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 0; }

.tile-preview-right.on-primary {
  border-radius: 0 6px 0 0; }

.tile-preview-left.tile-preview-right.on-primary {
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0; }
```

Change the `background-color:` line with any valid color..

[image]