# Change the color orange of Ambiance into another color?

Tags: themes, ambiance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the colors of the Radiance theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85786/how-do-i-change-the-colors-of-the-radiance-theme)

does anybody know how the change the color orange of Ambiance into another color? i hate orange!

do i have to change something in the file gtk.css?